How to Fix "Failed to Load Module Script" Error for React App Deployed on VPS with Nginx?
I'm a beginner trying to deploy my React application (static web pages) on a VPS using Nginx, and I'm running into a problem. After deploying, my app loads but doesn't display anything. The browser console shows the following error:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Here are the steps I followed:
Built my React app using Vite.
Transferred the dist folder to /var/www on my VPS.
Configured Nginx with the following settings:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jeevons.fr www.jeevons.fr;

    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Logs (optional)
    access_log /var/log/nginx/portfolioReact_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/portfolioReact_error.log;
}

Ensured my Vite config includes the base path and appropriate build settings:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/',
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'index.html',
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      },
    },
  },
})

Then I added the tag with the  in the head of the html file generated by vite.
Then I deactivated my browser's cache
Restarted Nginx after making these changes.
I've also ensured that the MIME types in Nginx are configured correctly and include application/javascript js; and application/javascript mjs;.
Despite this, I'm still facing the same error. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
